# Anonymous Users and managed navigation

Tags: client-object-model, navigation, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have a custom JavaScript that builds an extra navigation menu from a Managed Navigation `termset`.  Currently this is using JSOM and is great - when a user is logged in.  The problem is anonymous users cannot access it.  They also have issues with standard managed navigation links that are empty (this is fine because it doesn't break the entire thing, but it does break my custom one).

Is there a way to get this stuff without having to log in, or am I going to have to build a web part or control to make it happen with the server object model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this I created custom user controls that were able to access the managed metadata service even with an anonymous user.  I put them in a SharePoint Farm Solution, had them installed into the "CONTROLTEMPLATES" folder and they worked pretty beautifully.  Was also able to include a test page published to the _Layouts folder.