# How to make taxonomy picker accessible for anonymous users?

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, taxonomy, anonymous-authentication

I have a visual web part in which I have placed one taxonomy picker control to select the managed metadata for user.

The web part is going to be accessed by the anonymous users. But when as an anonymous users I click on picker it asks for credentials.

What is the way to make it accessible for the anonymous users?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.sharepointalist.com/2012/11/taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-anonymous.html) is also one another way to solve this.

As the taxonomy picker page belongs to `_layouts`, by default, it is not available to the anonymous users. Hence, we should set the property of the page `AllowAnonymousAccess` to `true`.

Go to the `_layouts` folder and find the `WebTaggingDialog.aspx` and place the below code.

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps other too.

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details from the link to your post, if the link breaks it will be of no help to future readers

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look over this blog post I found on setting anonymous access to application pages.  This page because it is coming from _layouts makes it a application page.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-application-page-for-anonymous-access.aspx

Also have look on this one:
[Anonymous Users and managed navigation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71273/anonymous-users-and-managed-navigation?rq=1)

Comment: Please add more details from the link to your post, if the link breaks it will be of no help to future readers